# Nginx Replace Query string redirect

Tags: regex, redirect, nginx

We were running on apache previously and used the below code to redirect/replace one of our query parameters.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^limit=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?product_list_limit=%1 [L,R=301]
```

This would successfully redirect the below URL

```
www.example.com/clothing.html?limit=all
```

TO

```
www.example.com/clothing.html?product_list_limit=all
```

I have used a htaccess redirect convertor that has produced the below. This doesn't work

```
    location ~ / {
    if ($query_string ~* "^limit=(.*)$"){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /$request_uri?product_list_limit=%1 redirect;
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `$request_uri` to construct the rewritten URI, as it also contains `?limit=all` - so your rewritten URI would look like: `/clothing.html?limit=all?product_list_limit=all`

The `rewrite` statement resets numeric captures, so you will need to use a named capture in the `if` statement.

The URI without query string is available as `$uri` or as a capture from the `rewrite` statement's regular expression.

Either of these forms should work for you:

```
if ($query_string ~* "^limit=(?<limit>.*)$") {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1?product_list_limit=$limit? redirect;
}
```

*Note the trailing `?` to prevent the original query string from being appended. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.*

Or:

```
if ($query_string ~* "^limit=(.*)$") {
    return 302 $uri?product_list_limit=$1;
}
```

The value of the `limit` argument is also available as `$arg_limit`, so you could also use this:

```
if ($arg_limit) {
    return 302 $uri?product_list_limit=$arg_limit;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_) for details.